# Helper functions to interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I got a interface used alot in the project and there is some logic that is recurring in the project.
Feel like this is not a good solution and I want to wrap this in some way.

Current code:

```
interface Person {
    status: StatusEnum
}

.... generic html  
return {adam.status === StatusEnum.someState && <div>This is in some state</div>}
```

What want to achieve is something like this:

```
interface Person {
    status: StatusEnum
}

class PersonHelper implements Person {
    isInSomeState = () => this.status === StatusEnum.someState
}

.... generic html  
return {adam.isInSomeState() && <div>This is in some state</div>}
```

Im sorry for the bad example but I hope you guys understand what I want.
And I only need to use the class in some places and not the complete project.
I usually add a helper.ts to handle this, but not I want to try this and explore if its a good pattern or not.

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a helper function?

```js
const isInSomeState = (person: Person): boolean => person.status === StatusEnum.someState

// .... generic html  
return {isInSomeState(adam) && <div>This is in some state</div>}
```

---

There is no extension method in JS as in C# ([C# extension method doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)). But there are 2 proposal which can achieve very close to what you want, the [This-Binding Syntax](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bind-operator) and the [The Pipeline Operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator). However, they have not been standardized yet and are only supported by some compilers.